# How to prove that models of indirect and direct RAM machines are equivalent?

Tags: formal-languages, turing-machines, formal-grammar

as in the title, I am looking for a formal proof how to show that models of indirect and direct RAM (random-access) machines are equivalent. 
I would really appreciate your help.

Comment: This is probably better suited for cs.stackexchange.com or even cstheory.stackexchange.com